# jQuery: check radiobutton when input text field onChange

Tags: jquery, radio-button, onchange

I am creating a questionnaire with PHP and jQuery. I have the following radio list:

```
    Question A:
    O Answer X
    O Answer Y
    O Answer Z
    O Other [input text field]
```

Now, when people directly select the input text field, I want the radiobutton of "Other" automatically be selected.

in HTML it looks like this:

```
         Answer X 

         Answer Y 

         Answer Z 

         Other
```

I have this in jQuery:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("input.customInput").focus(function () 
    {
    $('input:radio[name='question[A]']:checked').val() == 'Other');
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML code as well?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried to add the HTML, but I didn't get it to work. It is basically 4 radiobuttons with same name (different values) and a text field input for the "other" option.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible to do without JS:

```
<input type="radio" id="radioButton" />
<label for="radioButton">
    Other<input type="text" />
</label>
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vV4P9/

Comment: Hi Valentinas, thanks for your prompt reply, but that's not what I mean. I have an radiobutton option named "other". When people select that, they need to put a reason/explanation in a textfield/textarea. And when they do that, the radiobutton need to be selected automatically (if they forget to check it)

Comment: @user1169366 it's exactly what it does. Have you tried the demo? Colin Kenney made even better one: http://jsfiddle.net/pXx7q/

Comment: This doesnt work with Firefox sadly. When you click on the inputbox the elementfocus goes directly to the radiobutton. Effect: You cannot type into the field :(

Comment: Solution found (for my problem that is):
$('#element-to-click').click(function(){
  $('#radiobutton-to-check').trigger('click'):
});
that does the trick for me :)

See: http://jsfiddle.net/p8kvQ/

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with HTML by placing your text `input` inside the `label` for the "Other" radio button.

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pXx7q/)

Answer (score 0):

I found the code that apply for checkbox. So modify this one for the radio button. Hope this will help you

```
<input type="radio" name="mypet" id="radio_yes" value="Yes">
<input type="radio" name="mypet" id="radio_no" value="No">
<input type="text" name="boxname" id="boxname" onFocus="this.form.radio_yes.checked=true">
```